# WINAPI GetMessageW не перестает принимать сообщения после вызова PostQuitMessage

Tags: c++, c, winapi

По каким причинам происходит следующее, если в функцию `GetMessageW`, 2м параметром передать `HWND` окна, при вызове `PostQuitMessage` в процедуре окна при получении сообщения `WM_DESTROY`, окно просто закрывается, но не уничтожается, и цикл обработки сообщений окна продолжает работать? При это, если передать `NULL` или `nullptr`, то при таком раскладе все отрабатывает нормально?

Так работает нормально

```
MSG msg{};
while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
```

Но вот так, уже не завершится цикл.

```
MSG msg{};
while (GetMessageW(&msg, m_window_handle_, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
```

Помимо `GetMessageW`, c `PeekMessageW` происходит та же ситуация, т.е. сообщение `WM_QUIT` не доходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если получен `WM_DESTROY`, то окно уничтожается, его дескриптор становится невалидным, а функция `GetMessageW` будет продолжать вызываться с невалидным параметром и возвращать ошибку, но так как проверка возвращаемого значения сделана неверно, то цикл будет продолжать крутится. В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) прямо сказано, что так делать не стоит:

> Because the return value can be nonzero, zero, or -1, avoid code like this:
>
> `while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0))` ...